# list of elements like in facebook

Tags: java, android

i want to create an ap that it has a list in the bottom of the page and when i scroll over the screen down, the top of screen disappear and show only the list of elements (and when i scroll up again it show me the top of page again)- the same as in the facebook app..

i tried to implement it and this is my xml with a listview and scrollview, however it doesnt work as expected..

when i scroll page the page stay as is, and only when i scroll the list view , the list view goes down, however the top of the page remain and the list view remain in the same size)

how can i do the same list as in the facebook android app?

thanks alot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="#ffffff" >

     <!-- Header  Starts -->

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/header"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
         android:paddingBottom="5dip"
         android:paddingTop="5dip" >

         <!-- Logo Start -->
         <!-- Logo Ends -->

         <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
             android:id="@+id/profilePictureView1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
             android:layout_weight="1" >
         </com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView>

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/profileNameText"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:ems="10"
             android:inputType="textPersonName" />
     </LinearLayout>
     <!-- Header Ends -->

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/freinds"
         android:layout_width="50dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/detailsText"
         android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
         android:src="@drawable/logo" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/LikeImage"
         android:layout_width="50dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/freinds"
         android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/freinds"
         android:src="@drawable/logo" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/detailsText"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/header"
         android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/freinds"
         android:ems="10"
         android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

         <requestFocus />
     </TextView>

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/freinds" >

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/registerTwitter"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:text="Sale" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/registerFB"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:text="Deliver" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/clearCredentials"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:text="Group" />
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:hint="Search">                               
                </EditText>

                <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a little more complex than just xml layout, but maybe I miss understood, try playing a little with the scroll view events.

you want to display the top of page instantly, when user scroll up, so you need to register to the onscroll event of the scroll view, and check for the scroll direction, to display the top section of the page. is that more clear?

Comment: hi,thanks for answer, i dont understand you clearly, can you give me some example? i dont know how scroll view events will help me